# AutoHotKey (AHK) How to make wait for a command to finish before destroying GUI

Tags: function, send, autohotkey

```
Gui, Add, Button, w%buttonWidth% r%buttonHeight% gbutton1, &1. %var1%
button1:
WinActivate [title]
send %var1%
Gui Destroy
return
```

Currently when I press 1, the Gui is closed before it can type the variable. How do I either get it to type fast enough that I don't need to worry, or get it to wait for it to finish before closing?

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty version is to sleep a second assuming that is enough time.

```
Sleep, 1000
```

Also, if you want to type into the window you just activated,
you have to wait until it is active.
try

```
WinActivate [title]
WinWaitActive, [title]
```

The proper way is to check if the window that receives the variable has got it.
Your question doesn't provide enough detail to suggest a good way to do this.

Comment: Exactly. If the target window exposes a control whose contents can be read, you could implement a small waiting loop. Another approach would be to send it via clipboard and paste it. I'm not a fan of it, but you won't have to worry about how long to wait. Anyway, `SendMode, Input` could improve things, if not already used.

Comment: I think that your problem is that you define a GUI and then, without a return to close that section, you continue with the button1. Add a return after the GUI to separate the next section with the button1.

Comment: @robert the code above is only a part of the whole code - for example it has no `Gui Show` command so on it's own t would not even show the gui at all...

Comment: You (576i) are right there... But never the less, there should be no reason why the GUI closes, unless you hit a Gui Destroy, GUI Close or ExitApp....

Comment: I've had good luck by switching between `Send`, `SendInput`, and `SendRaw`. Currently getting best results with `Send`, for SharePoint Designer